# What Does Push -67 mean?

Tags: assembly

I am really so confused I just wanted to know this thing
in some dissemblers

IDA

**6A99 = PUSH FFFFFF99**

IN OTHER Dism

**6A99 = PUSH -67**

is there a different or what?

Comment: `FFFFFF99h` is the same as `-67h`, or `-99d` [link to hexadecimal calculator](http://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=ffffff99&operate=1&number2=67).

Answer (score 1):

6A is the opcode for "PUSH imm8".

imm8 is a signed byte, with values between -128 and 127.

Since 0x99 (153) as a signed byte is equal to -103 (-0x67), the disassembler can show it as either -67h or as a sign-extended integer (99h, ff99h or ffffff99h).